# Automagical Outlook 365 Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office365

Really getting frustrated at this. My company is using Outlook 365 for its Exchange services. I am trying to automate sending of exception emails from the client via exchange. However all of the literature on the subject seems to show that I have to provide a NetworkCredential with plain text username/passwords somehow. I am hoping to connect using the logged in user's account.

From an infrastructure point of view, I understand that Office 365 is authenticating users via ADFS, which is why bog standard negotiate is not working. It would also make sense that this is why I need the plain text password. However it would seem to me that there should be no reason why Kerberos style auth would not work.

In summary, is there some programmatic way to send emails via Outlook 365 without encoding privileged information into the application either the source or the config?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have two options BASIC+SSL, or ADFS, but it depends how your company is configured. I suggest you take a look at the 'Office 365 Identity Service Description.docx' document here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13602 to really understand what are the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However I am not interested in BASIC as that would require either storing the credentials in (essentially) plain text or having the user prompted for a username/password, which defeats the point of an automated mailer.

Comment: I understand, but it may be the only solution as NTLM/Kerberos may simply not be supported, unless you have ADFS.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. We are implementing ADFS (one of the few sane decisions in the company), however I am hitting a brick wall with NTLM/Kerberos, or does Kerberos have to be enabled on ADFS (by the way the Infrastructure people here only know what "Windows Auth" means)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you can login to the Office 365 Live with Internet Explorer without providing username\password than you should be able to get the NetworkCredintials for the currently logged in user with `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`.

Comment: Sigh...your answer led me towards the issue. Looked closer at the ADFS setup. Seems our admins feel that forms auth is "close enough", possibly because they would be unable to go the extra mile and setup true integrated auth.... With the red tape, I'd doubt that I could fix this. ARGH!